# Python, Matplotlib, plotting irregular grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

In Matplotlib, I am trying to plot the following grid:
[image]

The following formula gives me the length of each row:

```
xlen_max = 4
ylen = 7
for g in range(ylen):
    xlen = min(ylen-g, xlen_max)
    print(xlen)
4
4
4
4
3
2
1
```

I try to apply it to matplotlib as such:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ylen, xlen_max , figsize=(5, 5))
for aa, axlist[aa] in enumerate(axes):
    for a, ax in enumerate(axlist[aa]):
        xlen = min(ylen-g, xlen_max)
        if xlen > a  :
            axlist[aa][a].axis('off')
```

Or variations on that, but this returns various error and/or weird shaped plot grid.. Anyone as a quick idea/suggestion/hint what could be the way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `axe.set_visible(False)` to set invisible the axes that you don't need. Here is a example:

```
cnt = 1
fig, axes = plt.subplots(7, 4 , figsize=(5, 5))
for i, row in enumerate(axes):
    for j, axe in enumerate(row):
        if i > 3:
            if j > 3 - cnt:
                axe.set_visible(False)
    if i > 3:
        cnt += 1
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome thanks! What is the difference between `axe.set_visible(False)` and `axe.axis('off')` ?

Comment: I can not find a difference between the two. The result is the same.

Comment: `axe.axis('off')` just turns the axis lines, ticks and labels off. `axe.set_visible(False)` hides the whole axes artist, including anything plotted on it.