# Plotting images side by side using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering how I am able to plot images side by side using `matplotlib` for example something like this:

[image]

The closest I got is this:

[image]

This was produced by using this code:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2)
axarr[0,0] = plt.imshow(image_datas[0])
axarr[0,1] = plt.imshow(image_datas[1])
axarr[1,0] = plt.imshow(image_datas[2])
axarr[1,1] = plt.imshow(image_datas[3])
```

But I can't seem to get the other images to show. I'm thinking that there must be a better way to do this as I would imagine trying to manage the indexes would be a pain. I have looked through the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html#pylab-examples-subplots-demo) although I have a feeling I may be look at the wrong one. Would anyone be able to provide me with an example or point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66961099/7758804) from [@duhaime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1727392/duhaime) if you want a function to automatically determine the grid size.

Comment: maybe this is helpful: [Python, Matplotlib, plotting irregular grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41644180/python-matplotlib-plotting-irregular-grid/41644458#41644458)

Comment: Look at the [examples illustrating the use of `plt.subplots()`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html).

Comment: As an FYI it is acceptable to unaccept an old answer in favor of a new answer that is a better solution. Personally, I think your answer, YellowPillow, is a better solution to this question.

Comment: LOL. Looks like the OP was taking the self-driving car engineering class. I'm also taking that! It seems we both faced the same problems.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

The problem you face is that you try to **assign** the return of `imshow` (which is an `matplotlib.image.AxesImage` to an existing axes object.

The correct way of plotting image data to the different axes in `axarr` would be

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2,2)
axarr[0,0].imshow(image_datas[0])
axarr[0,1].imshow(image_datas[1])
axarr[1,0].imshow(image_datas[2])
axarr[1,1].imshow(image_datas[3])
```

The concept is the same for all subplots, and in most cases the axes instance provide the same methods than the pyplot (plt) interface. 
E.g. if `ax` is one of your subplot axes, for plotting a normal line plot you'd use `ax.plot(..)` instead of `plt.plot()`. This can actually be found exactly in the source from [the page you link to](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html#pylab-examples-subplots-demo).

Answer (score 69):

One thing that I found quite helpful to use to print all images :

```
_, axs = plt.subplots(n_row, n_col, figsize=(12, 12))
axs = axs.flatten()
for img, ax in zip(imgs, axs):
    ax.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 32):

You are plotting all your images on one axis. What you want ist to get a handle for each axis individually and plot your images there. Like so:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,1)
ax1.imshow(...)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax2.imshow(...)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,3)
ax3.imshow(...)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(2,2,4)
ax4.imshow(...)
```

For more info have a look here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html

For complex layouts, you should consider using gridspec: http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html

Answer (score 30):

If the images are in an array and you want to iterate through each element and print it, you can write the code as follows:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)) # specifying the overall grid size

for i in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)    # the number of images in the grid is 5*5 (25)
    plt.imshow(the_array[i])

plt.show()
```

Also note that I used subplot and not subplots. They're both different

Answer (score 17):

Below is a complete function `show_image_list()` that displays images side-by-side in a grid. You can invoke the function with different arguments.

1. Pass in a `list` of images, where each image is a Numpy array. It will create a grid with 2 columns by default. It will also infer if each image is color or grayscale.

```py
list_images = [img, gradx, grady, mag_binary, dir_binary]

show_image_list(list_images, figsize=(10, 10))
```

[image]

2. Pass in a `list` of images, a `list` of titles for each image, and other arguments.

```py
show_image_list(list_images=[img, gradx, grady, mag_binary, dir_binary], 
                list_titles=['original', 'gradx', 'grady', 'mag_binary', 'dir_binary'],
                num_cols=3,
                figsize=(20, 10),
                grid=False,
                title_fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Here's the code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def img_is_color(img):

    if len(img.shape) == 3:
        # Check the color channels to see if they're all the same.
        c1, c2, c3 = img[:, : , 0], img[:, :, 1], img[:, :, 2]
        if (c1 == c2).all() and (c2 == c3).all():
            return True

    return False

def show_image_list(list_images, list_titles=None, list_cmaps=None, grid=True, num_cols=2, figsize=(20, 10), title_fontsize=30):
    '''
    Shows a grid of images, where each image is a Numpy array. The images can be either
    RGB or grayscale.

    Parameters:
    ----------
    images: list
        List of the images to be displayed.
    list_titles: list or None
        Optional list of titles to be shown for each image.
    list_cmaps: list or None
        Optional list of cmap values for each image. If None, then cmap will be
        automatically inferred.
    grid: boolean
        If True, show a grid over each image
    num_cols: int
        Number of columns to show.
    figsize: tuple of width, height
        Value to be passed to pyplot.figure()
    title_fontsize: int
        Value to be passed to set_title().
    '''

    assert isinstance(list_images, list)
    assert len(list_images) > 0
    assert isinstance(list_images[0], np.ndarray)

    if list_titles is not None:
        assert isinstance(list_titles, list)
        assert len(list_images) == len(list_titles), '%d imgs != %d titles' % (len(list_images), len(list_titles))

    if list_cmaps is not None:
        assert isinstance(list_cmaps, list)
        assert len(list_images) == len(list_cmaps), '%d imgs != %d cmaps' % (len(list_images), len(list_cmaps))

    num_images  = len(list_images)
    num_cols    = min(num_images, num_cols)
    num_rows    = int(num_images / num_cols) + (1 if num_images % num_cols != 0 else 0)

    # Create a grid of subplots.
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_rows, num_cols, figsize=figsize)
    
    # Create list of axes for easy iteration.
    if isinstance(axes, np.ndarray):
        list_axes = list(axes.flat)
    else:
        list_axes = [axes]

    for i in range(num_images):

        img    = list_images[i]
        title  = list_titles[i] if list_titles is not None else 'Image %d' % (i)
        cmap   = list_cmaps[i] if list_cmaps is not None else (None if img_is_color(img) else 'gray')
        
        list_axes[i].imshow(img, cmap=cmap)
        list_axes[i].set_title(title, fontsize=title_fontsize) 
        list_axes[i].grid(grid)

    for i in range(num_images, len(list_axes)):
        list_axes[i].set_visible(False)

    fig.tight_layout()
    _ = plt.show()
```

Answer (score 9):

As per [matplotlib's suggestion for image grids](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/axes_grid1/simple_axesgrid.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4., 4.))
grid = ImageGrid(fig, 111,  # similar to subplot(111)
                 nrows_ncols=(2, 2),  # creates 2x2 grid of axes
                 axes_pad=0.1,  # pad between axes in inch.
                 )

for ax, im in zip(grid, image_data):
    # Iterating over the grid returns the Axes.
    ax.imshow(im)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

I end up at this url about once a week. For those who want a little function that just plots a grid of images without hassle, here we go:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_image_grid(images, ncols=None, cmap='gray'):
    '''Plot a grid of images'''
    if not ncols:
        factors = [i for i in range(1, len(images)+1) if len(images) % i == 0]
        ncols = factors[len(factors) // 2] if len(factors) else len(images) // 4 + 1
    nrows = int(len(images) / ncols) + int(len(images) % ncols)
    imgs = [images[i] if len(images) > i else None for i in range(nrows * ncols)]
    f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, figsize=(3*ncols, 2*nrows))
    axes = axes.flatten()[:len(imgs)]
    for img, ax in zip(imgs, axes.flatten()): 
        if np.any(img):
            if len(img.shape) > 2 and img.shape[2] == 1:
                img = img.squeeze()
            ax.imshow(img, cmap=cmap)

# make 16 images with 60 height, 80 width, 3 color channels
images = np.random.rand(16, 60, 80, 3)

# plot them
plot_image_grid(images)
```

Comment: This is nice, but doesn't work well if the number of images is a prime number. It also produces a lot of extra axes if the number of images is not evenly divisible by the number of `ncols`. Creating `imgs` doesn't _seem_ to do anything useful.

Comment: Yes it's not clear what should be plotted if the number of images to be plotted has no factors. One could easily remove those extra axes. `imgs` is to allow the zip operation; removing the extra axes would do the same trick

Comment: `'imgs` is not required. `zip` will only combine to the shortest length iterable. The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted.

Comment: Ah, very well! I had only ever zipped equal length iterables. In any event, happy coding!

Comment: This is a very helpful function. But `plt.show()` is needed to show the images.

Answer (score 2):

**Sample code to visualize one random image from the dataset**

```
def get_random_image(num):
    path=os.path.join("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/dataset/",images[num])
    image=cv2.imread(path)
    return image
```

Call the function

```
images=os.listdir("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/dataset")
random_num=random.randint(0, len(images))
img=get_random_image(random_num)
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

**Display cluster of random images from the given dataset**

```
#Making a figure containing 16 images 
lst=random.sample(range(0,len(images)), 16)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,12))
for index,value in  enumerate(lst):
    img=get_random_image(value)
    img_resized=cv2.resize(img,(400,400))
    #print(path)
    plt.subplot(4,4,index+1)
    plt.imshow(img_resized)
    plt.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)
#plt.savefig(f"Images/{lst[0]}.png")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

Plotting images present in a dataset
Here rand gives a random index value which is used to select a random image present in the dataset and labels has the integer representation for every image type and labels_dict is a dictionary holding key val information

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(5,5,figsize = (15,15))
ax = ax.ravel()
for i in range(25):
  rand = np.random.randint(0,len(image_dataset))
  image = image_dataset[rand]
  ax[i].imshow(image,cmap = 'gray')
  ax[i].set_title(labels_dict[labels[rand]])
  
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of other answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54681765/7758804), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41793987/7758804), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61114139/7758804) with a little, let me show you how to do something I didn't ask about.