# Subplotting image using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, opencv

I have got couple of images stored as an array using `cv2.imread` from the folder. I want to now display couple of images from the folder using subplots. Here is what I tried

```
w=10
h=10
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
columns = 4
rows = 5
for i in range(1, columns*rows +1):
    img = malaria_images[i]
    fig.add_subplot(rows, columns, i)
    plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

The result however looks like this. I am not sure where I went wrong . Any help would be appreciated. Thank you
[image]

Comment: Does this  [Plotting images side by side using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41793931/10733051) answer your question?

Comment: @sai Hi. Thank you for the reply. I tried all the method and it still shows me an empty grids

Comment: Have you noticed the concept of axes meant as a handle for each subplots? you cannot use `plt.imshow`

Comment: Is the content of the 'malaria_images' variable a file path or an image?

Comment: @r-beginners it is a list of all the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modified your solution to what is in the comments. Does this not show up?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

w=10
h=10
#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
columns = 4
rows = 5

fig, axes = plt.subplots(rows, columns, figsize=(8, 8))

i = 0
for r in range(rows):
    for c in range(columns):
        axes[r,c].imshow(malaria_images[i])
        i += 1

plt.show()
```