# Plot image using 16 small Images Python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I have made 16 grids of a single image.
as follow
[image]

So I have 16 separate images. I could plot it by first merging those 16 arrays.

I was thinking if there a way that I could just plot it using **Matplotlib grid** and removing the gaps between grids. but don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimum working example. you can replace the images array with the images you want to display. Credit to Chris Ivan for posting this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59043210/8755102) to another question

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
im = np.random.randint(0, 255, (256, 256), dtype=np.uint8)
images = [im] * 16
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
grid = ImageGrid(
    fig,
    111,
    nrows_ncols=(4, 4),
    axes_pad=0.0,
)
for ax, im in zip(grid, images):
    ax.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```