# Plotting multiple graphs on one figure generated from for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a dictionary of data frames and I am using the below code to generate a stacked bar chart for every data frame within the dict. The code prints every stacked bar chart as intended (each graph one after the other and below each other in notebook), but I want it to print each chart on one figure, lets say 4 rows with 3 columns for example.

```
for i, key in enumerate(d):
    plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (5,3)
    d[key].plot(kind = 'barh', width= 0.85, stacked = True, color = ['limegreen','gold', 'orange', 'red'])
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1.05, 1.025), title = "Categories")
    plt.xlabel('Cumulative Percent')
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
    plt.ylabel('Data Stream')
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.title(f'{key}')    
plt.show()
```

Comment: You can adapt the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54681765/8440629

Comment: lookup 'subplots' e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/python/matplotlib_subplot.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I plot separate Pandas DataFrames as subplots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483588/how-can-i-plot-separate-pandas-dataframes-as-subplots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using subplots:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {f"col_{i}": np.random.randint(0,100, 50) for i in range(12)}
)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 3, figsize=(25,20))
all_axs = axs.ravel()
for i, c in enumerate(df.columns):    
  ax = df[c].plot(kind = 'barh', 
                  width= 0.85, 
                  stacked = True, 
                  color = ['limegreen','gold', 'orange', 'red'], 
                  ax=all_axs[i])
  ax.legend(title = "Categories")
  ax.set_xlabel("Cumulative Percent")
  ax.set_ylabel("Data Stream")
  ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
  ax.invert_yaxis()

fig.tight_layout()
```

output:
[image]